# Joule heating for a fluid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics

Say you have a conductive liquid with a changing magnetic field going right through it, causing an electric current.  How exactly does the electric current travel and how could you calculate the effect of Joule heating on the liquid?

Comment: Are you looking for equations of magneto-hydrodynamics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called the *generalized Ohm's law*, which is given by:
$$
\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B} \approx \frac{ \mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} }{ n \ e } - \frac{ \nabla}{ n \ e } \cdot \left( \mathcal{P}_{e} + \frac{ m_{e} }{ m_{i} } \mathcal{P}_{i} \right) + \eta \ \mathbf{j} + \frac{ m_{e} }{ n \ e^{2} } \frac{ d \mathbf{j} }{ d t } \tag{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{j}$ is the total current density, $n$ is the total number density (assuming *quasi-neutrality*, i.e., $n_{e} = n_{i}$), $e$ is the fundamental charge, $\mathcal{P}_{s}$ is the pressure tensor of species $s$, $m_{s}$ is the mass of species $s$ ($s$ can be $e$ for electron or $i$ for ion), and $\eta$ is the scalar electrical [resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity).

The [Joule heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating) term is the $\eta \ \mathbf{j}$.  In linear circuits, one often assumes that Equation 1 reduces down to something akin to:
$$
\mathbf{E} \approx \eta \ \mathbf{j} \tag{2}
$$
and then one can use a relationship from [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem) which relates the rate of change of electromagnetic energy per unit volume into mechanical energy per unit volume (e.g., heat and/or particle kinetic energy).  This term is given by $\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{j}$ or approximated as $\eta \ j^{2}$.

In your specific example, Equation 2 would probably include the [Hall term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) as well, i.e., the $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}$ term.

Comment: Number density of electrons?  And does "of species" just mean, "of the fluid in question?"

Comment: Oh nevermind, a better question than the second one I asked is, "what exactly is 'e' and 'i'?"

Comment: @A.Frasch - e = electron and i = ion.  Electrons are generally the current carrying particles but ions can contribute as well in some cases.  If you mean a neutral conducting liquid like mercury, then electrons will be the current carriers and Equation 1 will reduce to Equation 2 (possibly with the Hall term as well if under and external magnetic field).

Comment: So in a liquid metal like iron, there wouldn't be any ions, right?

Comment: The nuclei that make up the liquid are effectively the ions, but in its neutral state, yes, one can treat this as an electron-only current.

Comment: Ok so number density would just be the number of nuclei+electrons divided by the volume of my previous liquid iron?

Comment: @A.Frasch - No, you would only consider the valence electrons for iron.  For each nuclei, there are 8 valence electrons, I believe.  You can look up the mass density of iron (in solid and liquid state) and then use stoichiometry to determine the number density of iron nuclei.  Multiply that value by 8 and you will have the number density of valence electrons (well a good enough approximation for most purposes).